# Get product ID in Bundle selection dropdown

Tags: magento-1.9, bundled-product

I'm using bundle products, and want to get the ID of simple products.

I was trying to get the ID from the product selection, but I think it's impossible.

My code:

```
<?php foreach ($_options as $_option): ?>
<?php
$_selections = $_option->getSelections();
foreach ($_selections as $_selection) {
    $id = $_selection->getProductId();          
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);

    $descripcion = $product->getDescription();
    $descriptions[ $id ] = $descripcion;
}
?>
```

But the `$_selection->getProductId()` its the product ID SELECTION, not the product ID from catalog.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get the ids of the bundle items like this:

```
$mainProductId = your bundle product id here
$children = Mage::getResourceModel('bundle/selection')
                 ->getChildrenIds($mainProductId, false);
```

$children will be an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
            [5] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [2] => 2
        )

)
```

The first index in the array (0, 1) is a numerical index for each option and the second dimension holds the product ids (1,5 for the first one, 2 for the second option)

Comment: Thanks a lot Marius! You always so successful! 
Next time i will call you instantly! =)
Pd: edit $children variable, you write childred.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go..

```
    <?php

    require_once('app/Mage.php');

    Mage::app();

    // Get bundle product
    $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('2');
    $selections = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
                ->getSelectionsCollection($product->getTypeInstance(true)
                ->getOptionsIds($product), $product);

    // get Selections
    foreach ($selections as $selection) {
    // Fetch information from selection
    print_r($selection->getId());
    }
?>
```