# M1 bundel products, get product Id by their value

Tags: magento-1.9, bundled-product

I created one bundle product, in bundle items I created one checkbox option with three products, ids 5,6 and 7.

In the frontend It have some values assigned to them, 13, 14, 15.

I want to get by ajax the product id selected, but I don't know how to do that with the value.

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, the answer came from [@APPSeCONNECT](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/79799/67658)

but, to put it on my own use:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($mainProductId);

$selections = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
                        ->getSelectionsCollection($product->getTypeInstance(true)
                        ->getOptionsIds($product), $product);

foreach ($selections as $selection) {

    $bundleIds[$selection->getData('selection_id')] = array(
        'product_id' => $selection->getId(),
        'selection_qty' => $selection->getData('selection_qty')
    );
}
```

I put the value of the option in the key of the array to access it faster